# preventDefault doesn't work on ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax

My `preventDefault`event doesnt work but can't udestand why. I was searching around but didn't realize where is the problem. If my case has answer somewhere please excuse me! This is my code:

```
var $vote_btn_up = $('.vote_comment_up_' + <?= $model->id ?>);
var $vote_btn_down = $('.vote_comment_down_' + <?= $model->id ?>);

$vote_btn_up.on('click', function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var $commentId = 0;
    var $postId = 0;
    if($vote_btn_up.data('comment_id') != 0){
        var $commentId = $vote_btn_up.data('comment_id');
    }
    if($vote_btn_up.data('post_id') != 0){
        var $postId = $vote_btn_up.data('post_id');
    }
    var $flag = $vote_btn_up.data('flag');
    var $userId = $vote_btn_up.data('user_id');
    $.ajax({
        method : 'post',
        url : '/admin/site/like-dislike',
        data : {flag : $flag, comment_id : $commentId, user_id : $userId, post_id : $postId},
        success : function( data ){
            console.log(data);
            if($flag == 1){
                $('.thumb-up_<?= $model->id ?>').text( data );
            }else if($flag == 2){
                $('.thumb-down_<?= $model->id ?>').text( data );
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: And the default would be what? What elements are we talking about here - actual buttons? Links? Something else? Please show some HTML that goes with this.

Comment: have you tried js `event.stopPropagation()` or jQuery's `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`?

Comment: Just return false: `$btn.on("click",function() { .... return false; }`

Comment: What does your "vote_btn_up" (sorry, can't bring myself to use the terrible practice of hungarian notation of adding $ to variable names, but off topic) actually do when you click it? (aside the from click handler here).   You can just stop it from doing whatever it was doing.  eg if it's a `button type=submit` then change it to `button type=button` .  If it's an anchor `a` then change it to `button type=button` (`a` should be used to link somewhere, not for buttons)

Comment: I changed them to `button` (they were all  an `a`) and used stopPropagation. That decide my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What behaviour do you want to prevent? `evt.preventDefault()` works if you have a form and the button is a submit button and you want to prevent submitting form. However these are many assumptions by me...

```js
var $vote_btn_up = $('.vote_comment_up');

$vote_btn_up.on('click', function (evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  console.log("log");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="http://google.de">
  <button type="submit" class="vote_comment_up">
    Button
  </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that You create more then one button:

```
var $vote_btn_up = $('.vote_comment_up_' + <?= $model->id ?>);
```

And if yes then next override earlier ... so try to put them for example in array and then You need to set handler for each button, like:

```
for(var i=0;i<=X;i++){
  $vote_btn_up[i].on('click',function(){

  });
});
```

Or:

```
$('.vote_comment_up_' + <?= $model->id ?>).each(function(){
  $(this).on('click',function(){

  });
});
```

Comment: No, please don't add event handlers in a loop.  OP could use `$(this)` inside the event handler, but don't do it this way. And you've not suggested changing the code inside the event handler, so this would have zero effect.